# How to make sound louder when record with asioout using NAudio?

Tags: asp.net, audio-recording, naudio

I have a trouble when recording audio file using asioout. When I playback file, the sound volume is too low. I hardly hear the sound. I cant raise output anymore than the current setting as the sound from loudspeaker will be much higher. Is there a way to make sound louder when recording file?
I use interface audio (presonus studio 18|24) with microphone as input device.

This is my code when record file.

```
public void OnAudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    if (Samples == null)
        Samples = new float[e.SamplesPerBuffer * e.InputBuffers.Length];
    e.GetAsInterleavedSamples(Samples);
    if (Writer != null)
        Writer.WriteSamples(Samples, 0, Samples.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution!. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085403/how-to-amplify-increase-bitrate-and-fadin-fadout-the-recorded-audio-in-windows), I decide to use FFMpeg to increase volume of recorded file. [Audio Volume Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume)